# Access VB how to have one module ignore a second module

Tags: ms-access

I have a form in access that I enter check numbers and it looks up the last check number in a table and I want to be able to put in text CASH instead of a check number but when I enter cash the second time Module 1 runs and then it will return the last check number from the database table.
I have two different modules in Access visual basic, how do I make the first module ignore the second if run and is true.

Module 1

```
   Private Sub CheckNum_BeforeUpdate(Cancel As Integer)
Dim rslt As String
    
    DoCmd.SetWarnings False
    If DCount("*", "FurChecks", "[CheckNum]='" & Me.CheckNum & "'") > 0 Then
      rslt = MsgBox("This number has already been entered. Do you wish to continue?", vbOKOnly)
        Me.Undo
        DoCmd.SetWarnings True
        
    Else
        'do nothing
    End If
  
End Sub
```

Module 2

```
 Private Sub CheckNum_LostFocus()
On Error GoTo Err_CheckNum_LostFocus

    Dim db As Database
    Dim rsCheckNumber As Recordset
    
    Set db = CurrentDb
    Set rsCheckNumber = db.OpenRecordset("LastUsedCheckNumber")


    If Me.TempNewCheckNumber = Me.CheckNum Then
     rsCheckNumber.MoveFirst
        rsCheckNumber.Edit
        rsCheckNumber!LastUsedCheckNumber = Me.TempNewCheckNumber
        rsCheckNumber.Update
    End If
    
Exit_CheckNum_LostFocus:
    rsCheckNumber.Close
    db.Close
    Set db = Nothing
    Set rsCheckNumber = Nothing

    Exit Sub

Err_CheckNum_LostFocus:
    MsgBox Err.Description
    Resume Exit_CheckNum_LostFocus
    
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Dave, your control events should not be in Regular modules they should be in the form module that they belong to. You should also check out this article on event order: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/order-of-events-for-database-objects-e76fbbfe-6180-4a52-8787-ce86553682f9#bm1 My suggestion would be to place all the code in the Before_Update event and do the logic checking there. You could also look at disabling/re-enabling events in your current code but that can get tricky. HTH

Answer (score 2):

First, you don't have two modules but *two subfunctions* in the code module of the form.

Next, cancel the update if you don't wish to update:

```vb
Private Sub CheckNum_BeforeUpdate(Cancel As Integer)
    
    If DCount("*", "FurChecks", "[CheckNum]='" & Me.CheckNum & "'") > 0 Then
        Cancel = True
    End If

    If Cancel = True Then
        MsgBox "This number has already been entered.", vbOKOnly
        Me.Undo
    End If
  
End Sub
```

Finally, move your *LostFocus* code to the *AfterUpdate* event:

```vb
Private Sub CheckNum_AfterUpdate()

    <snip>
```